# How to solve $5^{x + 1} = 3^{x + 2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $5^{x + 1} = 3^{x + 2}$.

I got this far, but I'm not sure how to continue:

\begin{align}
5^{x + 1} &= 3^{x + 2} \\
(5^x)(5^1) &= (3^x)(3^2) \\
5(5^x) &= 9(3^x)
\end{align}

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Use logarithms.

Comment: Hint: $\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^x = \; ?$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to
$$\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^x = \frac{9}{5}$$
Therefore, $x = \text{log}_{\frac{5}{3}} \frac{9}{5}$.

Comment: How do you get to $\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^x = \frac{9}{5}$ from $5(5^x) = 9(3^x)$ ?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly legitimate answer to a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur If $ab = cd$ and $a,b,c,d \neq 0$ then $\frac{b}{d} = \frac{c}{a}$. Also, $\frac{5^x}{3^x} = \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^x$.

Comment: @Aryan Beezadhur delete both sides by $3^x$

Comment: @ReneMorningstar do you mean *divide*, not delete?

Comment: @TheoBendit It sure is.  Sometimes bizarre trying to explain the motives of anonymous mathSE downvoters.

Comment: @Aryan Beezadhur divide this equation $5 \times 5^{x}=9 \times 3^{x}$ by $3^x$ and you will get $5 \times\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^{x}=9$. Divide by $5$ and get what is higher.

Answer (score 5):

Use natural logarithm:

$$5^{x+1}=3^{x+2}$$

$$\begin{align}&\implies (x+1)\ln 5=(x+2)\ln 3 \\
&\implies x\ln 5+\ln 5=x\ln 3+2\ln 3 \\ 
&\implies x(\ln 5-\ln 3)=2\ln 3-\ln 5 \\
&\implies x=\frac{2\ln 3-\ln 5}{\ln 5-\ln 3}. \end{align}$$